# UINavigationController's setViewControllers adds back button in IOS10

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios10, back-button

Noticed strange thing: when you replace view controllers stack in UINavigationController using setViewControllers:animated: back button is displayed during animation and disappears when animation completes. Found only in iOS10 (both device and simulator), iOS8 and 9 work correctly (no back button). Has anybody faced this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. But the back button shows only when the parameter animated is set to true.

Comment: Any solution/workaround? The only thing I see is to add empty left bar button, but looks a bit dirty.

Comment: got the same problem, ended up in `animated: false`

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem here but even with animated:false.
I also realized that the memory goes up when I keep repeating. Do they stay in background?

My code:

```
firstNavigationViewController.setViewControllers([firstRootViewController, secondViewController], animated: false)//
UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.rootViewController = firstNavigationViewController
```

My workaround is to set the following in viewWillAppear:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Protokoll"
```